# Using Simulink from c++ application

Tags: c++, matlab, simulink, mex

I would like to know if there is a way to use/communicate with Simulink from a c++ program. In this case Simulink is performing a **real-time-simulation** an should get its input data **during** simulation from the c++ controll-program. Also the simulation-data (output of blocks) from simulink should be accessible from the c++ program **during** simulation. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't show enough research or an attempt.

Answer (score 2):

For real-time processing you need to convert your Simulink model to C code using [Simulink Coder](https://www.mathworks.com/products/simulink-coder.html).

Being C code, the code resulting from the model can then be used any way you want (within your larger C application).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you would like to integrate your C++ code with Simulink and run the simulation.

According to the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/integrate-ccode-ccaller.html):

> The C Caller block allows you to bring C/C++ code into Simulink.
>
> The advantages of the C Caller block are:
>
> - Automated integration of simple C functions
> - Integration with Simulink Coverage, Simulink Test, and Simulink Design Verifier
> - Integration with Simulink Coder.
>
> To model dynamic systems, use the S-Function Builder instead.